# objective-c sql statements

Tags: sql

I am doing a sql database and was wondering if the following is possible?

Is it possible to have the following statement but more than one `where` condition. Such as `WHERE Country = 'Mexico and Name = 'Pete'`?

`SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country='Mexico';`

Thanks

Comment: Yes, what exactly is the problem here? SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country='Mexico' and Name = 'Pete' should work fine.

Comment: Any modern relational database is a "SQL datatabase". SQL is just a **query language** it is not a DBMS product. Even though your question does not contain anything that would be different between different DBMS products, it's still better if you specify which DBMS you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can definitely use `where` clause having multiple condition separated by `and` keyword.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country='Mexico' AND Name='Pete' AND ......
```

Comment: Strictly speaking you only have a single `where` that contains multiple conditions.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for misleading sentence. I have corrected it :)